# How do I rename an Apple Music station

Tags: itunes, apple-music

When I create a new radio station in Apple Music by selecting an existing song and then choosing "Create Station" from the right-click menu, it creates the station and gives it the name of the song I selected with the word "Radio" appended. How do I rename the station?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible... hoping Apple allows this in a future release.